# After Firebase push Notification, my APL goes dark screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

quickstart-ios

I use AppDelegate.m from quickstart-ios Firebase Messaging QuickStart.

I tried Firebase Messaging QuickStart, After setting of APNs, I send a Notifications 
from FirebaseNotifications. I’ve got the following push text using NSLog.

```
2016-12-06 19:52:21.946037 Rera[475:241532] Connected to FCM.
2016-12-06 19:52:21.975597 Rera[475:241532] {
    "collapse_key" = "com.repoject.reraevent";
    from = 298280533278;
    notification =     {
        badge = 0;
        body = test; 
        e = 1;
        sound = default;
    sound2 = default;
    };
}
```

it seem to be good work of FirebaseNotifications
In AppDelegate.m environment, it works well.
But my application dose not work at all. It become dark screen.
Also Push message dose not appear my application both foreground and background. 
I can see the Alert screen on iPad but iPhone 6s plus, start screen appear and goes to dark screen.

What is the problem?
Any support appreciated.
Shoji

Comment: I checked it back to original AppDelegate.m, my APL works without error.

Comment: AppDelegate.m from quickstart-ios has lot of functions.  Is there any function to delete or investigate?

Comment: I want A little function to get only push notification, Is there any example of AppDelegate.m ?